# How to test if an event was subscribed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an attached behavior that subscribes to a TabItem's IsVisibleChanged method. I want to write a unit test to verify that this event is being subscribed in the attached behavior.

Something like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(myTabItem.IsVisibleChanged != null);
```

I can't do this because my test is outside of the TabItem class so it can not test equality of an event.

I've also tried this:

```
private class MyTabItem : TabItem
{
    public bool IsVisibleChangedNull()
    {
        return base.IsVisibleChanged == null;
    }
}
```

This also doesn't work. Does anyone have a good way to test this?

Comment: In this circumstance, you might need to use reflection and white-box testing to access the subscriber list (backing delegate).  Note that the name of the backing delegate field most likely is not `IsVisibleChanged`, you'll have to find out what it is, and possible look it up in a dictionary (WinForms uses dictionaries of events to space memory, not sure if WPF does also).

Comment: As an aside, is this really something that requires a test?  Is this a piece of code that's likely to break and, if it does, wouldn't the bug be immediately obvious?  I've just never considered testing that an event handler is subscribed to... I test my algorithms, the complicated stuff.

Comment: @EdS. It's a valid argument. I wouldn't be heartbroken if I couldn't unit test this section of code. However I usually try to get as close to 100% coverage as I can.

Comment: Is `IsVisibleChanged == null` a hard guarantee made by your class right after construction that you want to rely upon anyway? There are quite a number of people that make sure *every* event has a do-nothing subscriber right when the class is constructed (so that the event does not need a null check before invoking it). Personally I don't like it, but it's a perfectly valid choice, and your test would start failing if someone on your team (if you are part of a team) thinks it would make sense for this particular event.

Comment: @hvd I would prefer to check that IsVisibleChanged has the correct handler to the method implemented in the attached behavior class, but that seems even trickier to test without adding unnecessary complexity to the attached behavior.

Comment: @Justin984 If the `IsVisibleChanged` backing field is visible (exactly in those cases where `IsVisibleChanged == null` is a valid test), and you know the method you want to test for, you could call [`Delegate.GetInvocationList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) to see exactly which subscribers the event has.

Comment: @hvd I wasn't aware that method existed, I'm looking into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to verify that the event is successfully subscribed is to do something that would trigger the event and the have code in the event handler such that it needs to run for the test to succeed:

```
bool fired = false;

foo.SomeEvent += ()=> fired = true;
foo.DoSomethingToFireEvent();

Assert.IsTrue(fired);
```

Comment: This doesn't tell you if other handlers got correctly attached.

Comment: @BenVoigt Right. The event is subscribed from within the attached behavior, not the unit test.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, if they're from outside the scope of this test, I don't see why they should.  If they're attached within the scope of this test then you can use this method; you simply need to ensure that the handler performs some observable side effect.